# Rails bootstrap carousel loading slowly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have used Rails and bootstrap to build a library of attacks (stored in the database).

It is a bootstrap carousel, on the left 3rd of page there is a vertical list of names of attacks that can be clicked on to bring up more info about that attack in the inner-carousel. The inner carousel is a vertical scrollable, dominating the remainder of the page. The more information section have embedded youtube videos, images, descriptions, and will have more info.

Currently there are well over 100 and they all load at once, needless to say it is SUPER slow. I am wondering if there is a way to "lazy-load" the entire inner-carousel easily.

I have been looking at something like this as a solution:

http://purelywebdesign.co.uk/tutorial/lazy-load-images-in-a-rails-application/

but It doesn't really help me as far as the youtuble videos and other info.

below is my code:

**attack_library.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid" id="lib_carousel_wrapper">
    <div id="attack_library_carousel" class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="lib_attack_col_wrapper">
            <div class="darkest_background  attack_lib_header">
                <h3>attack</h3>
            </div>


            <div id="custom-search-input">
                <div class="input-group col-md-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" placeholder="Find an attack" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                          <button class="btn btn-info btn-lg" type="button">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i>
                          </button>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>            


            <ul id="attack_library_list_group" class="list-group">
            <% @attacks.each_with_index do |attack,index| %>
              <% if index == 0 %>
              <li data-target="#attack_library_carousel" data-slide-to="<%= index%>" class="list-group-item active"><h4><%= attack.name%></h4></li>
          <% else %>
            <li data-target="#attack_library_carousel" data-slide-to="<%= index%>" class="list-group-item"><h4><%= attack.name%></h4></li>
          <% end %>
        <% end %>
            </ul>

        </div>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" id="lib_description_col_wrapper">
        <div class="darkest_background  attack_lib_header">
            <h3>Information</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel_inner_lib">
        <% @attacks.each_with_index do |attack,index| %>
        <% if index == 0 %>
          <div class="item active">
        <% else %>
          <div class="item">
        <% end %>
            <h1><%= attack.name%></h1>

            <h2>Description</h2>
            <p> <%= attack.description%></p>

            <h2>Video</h2>
            <iframe width="400" height="240" src="<%= attack.link%>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

            <h2>image</h2>
            <%= image_tag("attack.jpg") %>

            <h2>Affected</h2>
            <p>Primary -  <%= attack.primary_affected%></p>
            <p>Secondary -  <%= attack.secondary_affected%></p>
            <p>Tertiary -  <%= attack.tertiary_affected%></p>

            <h2>Stats</h2>
            <p>Max: 540pts </p>
      <% end %> 
        </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

**attack.js**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var clickEvent = false;
      $('#attacks_library_carousel').carousel({
          interval:  0  
      }).on('click', '.list-group li', function() {
              clickEvent = true;
              $('.list-group li').removeClass('active');
              $(this).addClass('active');       
      }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
          if(!clickEvent) {
              var count = $('.list-group').children().length -1;
              var current = $('.list-group li.active');
              current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
              var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
              if(count == id) {
                  $('.list-group li').first().addClass('active');   
              }
          }
          clickEvent = false;
      });

});
```

**attacks_controller.rb**

```
class AttackssController < ApplicationController
  def library
    @attacks = Attack.all
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I ended up doing to make this fast, was rendering partials inside of the inner-carousel.

**attacks_controller.rb**

```
class AttackssController < ApplicationController
  def library
    @attacks = Attack.name
  end
end
```

Then I created used the names to create the list of attacks on the left as well as save the name of the attack in the inner-carousel.

**attack_library.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div class="section">
  <div class="container-fluid" >
    <div class="carousel" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4" id="ex_lib_attack_col_wrapper">             
           <ul class="list-group">
            <% @attack_names.each_with_index do |attack,index| %>
              <% if index == 0 %>
              <li data-target="#attack_library_carousel" data-slide-to="<%= index%>" class="list-group-item active"><h4><%= attack.name%></h4></li>
              <% else %>
              <li data-target="#attack_library_carousel" data-slide-to="<%= index%>" class="list-group-item"><h4><%= attack.name%></h4></li>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
           </ul>

        </div>
      <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8" id="ex_lib_description_col_wrapper">
        <div class="carousel-inner" id="carousel_inner_ex_lib">
        <% @attack_names.each_with_index do |attack,index| %>
          <% if index == 0 %>
          <div class="item active" data-url="/attacks/show_library_attack/<%=attack.slug%>" data-slide-number="0">
          <% else %>
          <div class="item" data-url="/attacks/show_library_attack/<%=attack.slug%>">
          <% end %>

          </div><!-- End Item -->
      <% end %> 
        </div><!-- End Carousel Inner -->
      </div>
    </div><!-- End Carousel -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Passing it to js. I then used the name that is stored as data url to do a "load" in js.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can simply use Ajax requests to fetch a certain number of attacks when the user scrolls to a given position. For example

**Jquery**

```
var itemPosition = $(".item").offset().top; 
var carouselPosition = $("#carousel_inner_lib").offset().top;
var difference = carouselPosition - itemPosition;
```

When the `var difference` variable reaches a certain preset threshold (maybe 50px) Use an Ajax request like so.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '/items/:offset',
    success: function(data){
      // append data to attacks list here and increment :offset.
    }
});
```

But note that you will have to update all element positions on scroll.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was hoping to be able to load all the names at once but then load the more information section a few at a time.